# Polymer element not working in windows safari browser?

Tags: polymer-1.0

I am creating a polymer element, which is not supporting in windows safari browser. It is showing error like this -

[image]

How to override this problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you check Polymer's [website](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/browsers) you'll find that they support `Safari 7+`. And for windows if i'm correct 5 is the last version for Safari. So, you should not try Safari in windows for Web-components

Comment: yeah, actually for windows 5.7 is the last version.